# Regarding Afghan nationals visiting Azerbaijan

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, azerbaijan, afghan-citizens

I heard that visas will be given to Afghan passport holders upon arrival to the Azerbaijan airport. How true is that? A second question: what nearby country issues an Azerbaijani visa for Afghan nationals?

Answer (score 2):

[It's apparently not the case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Azerbaijan), except if you have a letter of invitation from the State Migration Service. Wikipedia also points to this [list of diplomatic missions of Azerbaijan](http://www.mfa.gov.az/files/file/dip_missions%20abroad%2015_05_2013.pdf).